# Android Studio doesn't show imageView on api 23

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have two problems :(

First thing you have to know; When i run my app on the api 27 or 28, I don't have problem.

but when I try this (running) on api 23 (android 6.0) my build is crashing.
And I take a error like this 'Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped'

After that, I realize that My imageViews doesn't seem in the Desing mode when Api 23 selected.

What's the problem with Api 23? I wanna build for android 6.0 to, what I have to do?

---

## Solved

I copy my picture to mipmap folder problem solved!

Comment: Hey, please share some logs via log cat, so we can understand what the problem actually is.

Comment: 12-15 22:21:46.802 6527-6527/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.fendercalangibson.catchtheeric-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied

Comment: This is first error

Comment: Try disabling instant run. and clean the workspace, rebuild the project.

Comment: I've been trying to solve it for 4 days, but i could'nt. I tried that your says, but did not help me :(